# Escape filenames the same way Bash does it

Tags: linux, bash, escaping

When I use the "tab" key in `bash` (when you have started to type the filename and you want it to complete), `bash` escapes the filename correctly, and if I use exactly that "escaped" filename, it works.

For Instance:

`An-Beat - Mentally Insine (Original Mix).mp3` => After `bash` Escapes It Using "TAB" 
`An-Beat\ -\ Mentally\ Insine\ \(Original\ Mix\).mp3`

I'm search for a function for `bash` that will escape a filename the same way "tab" escapes filenames.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio, that sums of my feelings about this question far better than I could have said it. :)

Comment: @Ignacio Indeed.  This seems to be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607502/curl-complex-with-bash), and getting quotes in the variable value won't help at all -- he needs them *around* the variable substitution, and a way to loop over values, and...

Answer (score 48):

Use `printf` (1):

```
x='a real \good %* load of c$rap'
x=$(printf '%q' "$x")
echo $x
```

will return

```
a\ real\ \\good\ %\*\ load\ of\ c\$rap
```

Comment: If x is a parameter of a shell script, users can set x contains ('), and I must replace (') to (\'). Is there any easy way to handle such case?

Comment: @zsxwing it already does, just start with `x="'"` to demonstrate! (`printf '%q" "'"` prints `\'`)

Comment: %q in an unknown directive to printf on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @user3690202 Use bash printf (it's a builtin, not the /usr/bin/printf or so if you have it)

Comment: A very special case that may not work : echo $(printf '%q' "test $2 3.jpeg")... If the file is originating from windows which allows $. $2 will be evaluated and return empty thus resulting in test\ \ 3.jpeg.

Comment: @airboss Huh. That's "Garbage In Garbage Out". The problem is not `printf` but you passing it invalid input. Just use `printf '%q' 'test $2 3.jpeg'` as you would anywhere where you want unexpanded string literals ([man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash))

Comment: @airboss Also, if you just used the answer code as given (instead of changing it without understanding it): http://ideone.com/HdtYoJ

Comment: @sehe Sometimes the Garbage in cannot be controlled if its coming from users. This was just one of the example. Another made-up example of a filename: Name #1 [valid] : With.Special Ã¤ chars * 3 (2) incl & as ' well.jpg. And i see worse.

Comment: @airboss Your users don't edit the script. Here's all your inputs and more. http://ideone.com/RgXggz You can clearly see there's no problem with it, whatsoever.

Comment: @sehe, What does `%q` do?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei well not to state the obvious, but... it escapes the string value in a way that it's safe for use in a shell expression. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf and of course [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)

Comment: Thanks, `Print the associated argument shell-quoted, reusable as input` is what I was looking for.

Comment: I've found that this works perfectly with one notable exception: paths that begin with tilde.  Anyone have a workaround for that?

Comment: @Compholio it works fine, unless you don't supply the input in a context that doesn't do tilde expansion: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75bcbc0d07d060dc

Comment: @sehe With your example, I would expect this to work: `eval ls $myvar` but because of the escaped tilde it does not.

Comment: @Compholio "It does not work" - how? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bdaee7d64b12463 Code talks. It does work, and besides, `eval` is it's own can of worms, so maybe separate the concerns of escaping and `eval` which introduces its own expansion context(s)

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to elaborate on sehe's response on this one.

If you want to pass the argument to be converted as a shell script parameter, encase the parameter in "'s.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(printf '%q' "$1")
echo $x
```

I really like the printf solution, since it does every special character, just like bash.

Comment: This is a comment, not elaboration, IMO

Answer (score 4):

```
$ string="An-Beat - Mentally Insine (Original Mix).mp3"
$ echo ${string// /\\ }
An-Beat\ -\ Mentally\ Insine\ (Original\ Mix).mp3
$ string=${string// /\\ }
$ echo ${string//(/\\( }
An-Beat - Mentally Insine \( Original Mix).mp3
```

Comment: This doesn't escape the parenthesis symbols

Answer (score 4):

The solution from "sehe" works fine, in addition, you can also use double quotes (") instead of single apostrophe (') to by able to use variables:

```
x="a real \good %* load of crap from ${USER}"
echo $(printf '%q' "$x")
```

Of course the string may not contain $ or " itself or you have to escape those manulally by splash \$.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls  --quoting-style=escape /somedir
```

this will output the escaped filenames, and also work with unicode characters, printf method does not work with Chinese, it outputs something like $'\206\305...'

Answer (score 2):

I may be a little late to the party but what worked for me is:

```
ls  --quoting-style=shell-escape
```

This way it also escapes characters like `!` or `'`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm search for a function for bash that will escape a filename the same way "tab" escapes filenames.

##### Solution to get escaped full paths

I've created a portable function to get all the escaped paths to all items in the current directory, tested on macOS and Linux (requires GNU bash installed).

```
escpaths() {
    find "$PWD" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$0"' {} | sort
}
```

Here's a rigorous test case scenario:

```
# Generate test directory, containing test directories and files.
mkdir 'test dir'; cd 'test dir'

mkdir '\dir  with\ backslashes\\\'
touch '\file with \\backslashes\'
touch 'An-Beat - Mentally Insine (Original Mix).mp3'
mkdir 'crazy(*@$):{}[]dir:'
mkdir 'dir with 字 chinese 鳥鸟 characters'
touch $'file\twith\tmany\ttabs.txt'
touch 'file @*&$()!#[]:.txt'
touch 'file
with
newlines.txt'
```

Executing `escpaths` in the test directory `test dir` gives the escaped output:

```
$'/.../test dir/file\nwith\nnewlines.txt'
$'/.../test dir/file\twith\tmany\ttabs.txt'
/.../test\ dir
/.../test\ dir/An-Beat\ -\ Mentally\ Insine\ \(Original\ Mix\).mp3
/.../test\ dir/\\dir\ \ with\\\ backslashes\\\\\\
/.../test\ dir/\\file\ with\ \\\\backslashes\\
/.../test\ dir/crazy\(\*@\$\):\{\}\[\]dir:
/.../test\ dir/dir\ with\ 字\ chinese\ 鳥鸟\ characters
/.../test\ dir/file\ @\*\&\$\(\)\!#\[\]:.txt
```

##### Solution to get escaped basenames only

This (also portable) function will get you the escaped basenames of all items in the current directory (this time excluding the current directory).

```
escbasenames() {
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec printf '%s\0' "$(basename {})" \; | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "${0#./}"' {} | sort
}
```

Running `escbasenames` in the same test directory `test dir` gives the escaped basenames:

```
$'file\nwith\nnewlines.txt'
$'file\twith\tmany\ttabs.txt'
An-Beat\ -\ Mentally\ Insine\ \(Original\ Mix\).mp3
\\dir\ \ with\\\ backslashes\\\\\\
\\file\ with\ \\\\backslashes\\
crazy\(\*@\$\):\{\}\[\]dir:
dir\ with\ 字\ chinese\ 鳥鸟\ characters
file\ @\*\&\$\(\)\!#\[\]:.txt
```

##### Final notes

Note that if the path/filename contains newlines or tabs, it will be encoded as an ANSI-C string. Autocompletion in the terminal also completes with ANSI-C strings. Example ANSI-C string autocompletion outputs would look like `my$'\n'newline$'\n'dir/` or `my$'\t'tabbed$'\t'file.txt`.