# PostgreSQL/PostGIS: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" SQL state: 42601

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to import a database to use on PostGis.
The file has more than 1GB and the main restore file has a lot of structures like this:

```
\i $$PATH$$/16600.dat
```

Where $$PATH$$ is the path on the operational system. 
Then when i try to put the right path

```
\i F:\Faculdade\Banco de Dados II\bc250_pgis20_dump\16600.dat
```

i got the following errors:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1632: \i 'F:\Faculdade\Banco de Dados II\bc250_pgis20_dump\16599.d...
           ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 52941
```

Please, help me. My head is hurting cause i'm trying to fix this all night long. 
PS: I'm using PgAdmin3 and Windows.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858176/how-to-escape-spaces-in-path-during-scp-copy-in-linux) ?

Comment: What is on the previous line? ( hint: try to put `\echo OMG` on the previous line to see if the psql/pgadmin parser is out of sync) But: the previous suggestion looks even simpler (I don't know windows, I think is is terrible)

Comment: Guys, i restored the database using the backup/restore tool.
But i'm gonna take a look at that link. 

Thanks for the help :)