# scp fails with "protocol error: filename does not match request"

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a script that uses SCP to pull a file from a remote Linux host on AWS.  After running the same code nightly for about 6 months without issue, it started failing today with `protocol error: filename does not match request`.  I reproduced the issue on some simpler filenames below:

```
$ scp -i $IDENT $HOST_AND_DIR/"foobar" .
# the file is copied successfully

$ scp -i $IDENT $HOST_AND_DIR/"'foobar'" .
protocol error: filename does not match request
# used to work, i swear...

$ scp -i $IDENT $HOST_AND_DIR/"'foobarbaz'" .
scp: /home/user_redacted/foobarbaz: No such file or directory
# less surprising...
```

The reason for my single quotes was that I was grabbing a file with spaces in the name originally.  To deal with the spaces, I had done `$HOST_AND_DIR/"'foo bar'"` for many months, but starting today, it would only accept `$HOST_AND_DIR/"foo\ bar"`.  So, my issue *is* fixed, but I'm still curious about what's going on.

I Googled the error message, but I don't see any real mentions of it, which surprises me.

Both hosts involved have `OpenSSL 1.0.2g` in the output of `ssh -v localhost`, and `bash --version` says `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a helpful comment but I've just started getting this today for something I've had running hourly for a month. Only happened after installing updates on ubuntu.

Comment: I posted another question about this feature here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499958/why-does-scps-strict-filename-checking-reject-quoted-last-component-but-not-oth

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I ended up having a look through the source code and found the commit where this error is thrown:

[GitHub Commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/391ffc4b9d31fa1f4ad566499fef9176ff8a07dc#diff-9f340c228413d5a9a9206ea2ed2bc624)

> remote->local directory copies satisfy the wildcard specified by the
>   user.
>
> This checking provides some protection against a malicious server
>   sending unexpected filenames, but it comes at a risk of rejecting
>   wanted files due to differences between client and server wildcard
>   expansion rules.
>
> For this reason, this also adds a new -T flag to disable the check.

They have added a new flag `-T` that will ignore this new check they've added so it is backwards compatible. However, I suppose we should look and find out why the filenames we're using are flagged as restricted.

Comment: very interesting!  I was pretty sure I hadn't updated any software that would also update openssh stuff, but I just learned about `/var/log/apt/history.log*` and it seems like openssh was updated this morning by `/usr/bin/unattended-upgrade`.  The last time it was automatically upgraded before that was November 2018.  I didn't know that my (very vanilla, uncustomized) system was being automatically updated at all.  I don't see anything saying that this auto-updating is the default on EC2 Ubuntu, but I guess it must be.

Comment: We encountered the same problem and -T fixed it for us as well. The funny thing is that we're using absolute paths without any wildcards in both src and dst. I'm tempted to say it's a bug in the commit referenced above. In our environment the scp command is being called by a PHP program which is executed by a cron job.

Comment: this comes in handy when you are doing `scp -T "foo@bar:'/long filename/with annoying/spaces in it/that you dont want/to escape'"`

Comment: Adding `alias scp='scp -T'` to your `.bashrc` will do this automatically.

Comment: `that will ignore this new check they've added so it is backwards compatible`

That's not how backwards-compatibility works...

Comment: In the middle of 2021 this is actual. For modern scp this is the answer. But for older i.e. CentOS 7.8, there is no -T option. Then user may try to use `sftp` instead of `scp` OR use `sshpass + scp`. The last construction is used successfully in Teamcity between CentOS-based agent and Windows SSH server.

Comment: This bug is reported at https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2966

Comment: The original exploit is documented [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46516).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had `[]` characters in the filename that needed to be escaped using one of the options listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364170/3515141). for example:

```
scp USERNAME@IP_ADDR:"/tmp/foo\[bar\].txt" /tmp
```