# Preserving escape characters in bash function

Tags: bash, escaping, special-characters, argument-passing

I'm having trouble trying to write a simple bash function that will move a file to a designated folder. The code I have written is as follows:

```
mv_file() {
  DESTINATION_FOLDER="~/Whatever"
  mv $1 $DESTINATION_FOLDER
}
```

The issue is however that `$1` often contains escaped characters such as `~/\[Bracketed\]File` which when passed to `$1` no longer contains the `\` character and ends up looking for `~/[Bracketed]File` which isn't a valid file/path. I've gone through the other questions on this topic yet I don't think the solutions pertain to this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't quoting the variable help this? `mv "$1" $DESTINATION_FOLDER`

Comment: Nope, unfortunately when I quote it, the forward slashes still don't exist. For example when I `echo "$1"` I get `~/[Bracketed]File` :(

Comment: Then I guess you need to _pass_ to command line params in quotes. E.g. `yourscript.sh "~/\[Bracketed\]File"`.

Comment: Hmm I see, but that would be at the expense of auto-fill which would be cumbersome. I could auto-fill, and then wrap in quotes, but isn't there a better way?

Comment: I don't really get your point about about auto-fill. Is this script automated somehow? Is the source folder parameter a user provided value?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just meant that when you write quotes, tab-completion won't work to pick up the file name.

Comment: You need to escape all of the special characters, which can be done with `printf`. Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608112/escape-filenames-using-the-same-way-bash-do-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that two changes are needed.  First, you likely want to replace:

```
DESTINATION_FOLDER="~/Whatever"
```

with:

```
DESTINATION_FOLDER=~/"Whatever"
```

The shell only does tilde expansion is the tilde is *unquoted*.

Second, if the first argument to the script is correctly quoted (not clear from the question), then you need to replace:

```
mv $1 $DESTINATION_FOLDER
```

with:

```
mv "$1" "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with tilde, didn't know :). Unfortunately when I wrap `$1` in quotes however it doesn't change the forward slashes from disappearing. For example when I `echo "$1"` I still get `~/[Bracketed]File`

Comment: @aMat Would you clarify the issue with the bracketed path.  You write "`~/[Bracketed]File` which isn't a valid file/path".  On your filesystem, what is the valid path?  Also, could this be another tilde inside quote issue?

Comment: Yea sure. So I would evoke the function by writing `mv_file ~/\[Bracketed\]File` and then it would spit out the following error `mv: rename /Users/aMat/[Bracketed]File to ~/Whatever: No such file or directory`. I suspect the problem is that I need the escape characters there for the `mv` call.

Comment: Update! Sorry for the confusion man but you were absolutely right on both accounts! My problem was i didn't start a new bash session so i didn't register any of the changes. Thanks again man, both tips were needed to fix this!