# bash: exact reproduction of escaped quotes in a JSON file

Tags: json, bash, while-loop, printf, jq

How is it possible to reproduce a string exactly as it is in a while-read loop?

Here's the specific example.

I am reading a JSON file:
`{"key":"value with a \"quote\" inside"}` and piping this into a while-read loop:

```
echo "{\"key\":\"value with a \\\"quote\\\" inside\"}" | jq -rc '.' | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

This is the output I see:

```
{"key":"value with a "quote" inside"}
```

The quotes inside the field disappear after being echo-ed. I would like to preserve those escape characters, so I looked at possible solutions and I suspect that `printf` can help ([Escape FileNames Using The Same Way Bash Do It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608112/escape-filenames-using-the-same-way-bash-do-it)). By changing `echo` to `printf '%q'`:

```
echo "{\"key\":\"value with a \\\"quote\\\" inside\"}" | jq -rc '.' | while read line; do printf '%q' "$line"; done
```

I get the following:

```
\{\"key\":\"value\ with\ a\ \"quote\"\ inside\"\}
```

Unfortunately, now the previously unescaped quotes are also escaped (in addition to all the other escapes). Could you tell me how can I achieve the following output within a `while read` loop?

```
{"key":"value with a \"quote\" inside"}
```

Comment: use `read -r` to not interpret backslashes

Comment: @jandob: Thank you! Could you put this as an answer, which I will accept. It works! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "{\"key\":\"value with a \\\"quote\\\" inside\"}" | while read -r line
do 
    echo "$line"
done
```

works for me. With the -r switch read does not interpret backslashes. But

```
echo '{"key":"value with a \"quote\" inside"}' | while read -r line
do 
    echo "$line"
done
```

works as well

Comment: Yep you're right i just wanted to eliminate some of the backslashes. Corrected it above...