# bash: dealing with strange filenames tail invalid option --1

Tags: bash, filenames, tail

I want my script to find a file (in the current directory) with the first line equal to `START`. Then that file should have `FILE <file_name>` as the last line. So I want to extract the `<file_name>` - I use `tail` for this. It works ok for standard file names but cracks for nonstandard file names like `a a` or `a+b-c\ = e` with `tail` reporting `tail option used in invalid context -- 1`

Here is the beginning of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

next_stop=0;

# find the first file
start_file=$(find . -type f -exec sed '/START/F;Q' {} \;)
mv "$start_file" $start_file       # << that trick doesn't work

if [ ! -f "$start_file" ]
then
  echo "File with 'START' head not found."
  exit 1
else
    echo "Found $start_file"
fi

# parse the last line of the start file
last_line=$(tail -1 $start_file)    # << here it crashes for hacky names
echo "last line: $last_line"
if [[ $last_line == FILE* ]] ; then 
    next_file=${last_line#* }
    echo "next file from last line: $next_file"
elif [[ $last_line == STOP ]] ; then
        next_stop=true;
    else
        echo "No match for either FILE or STOP => exit"
        exit 1
    fi
```

I tried to embrace the `find` output with braces this way

```
mv "$start_file" $start_file
```

but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occur to the character of the escape.
You should write it start_file variable in quotes.
last_line=$(tail -1 $start_file) --> last_line=$(tail -1 "$start_file")

Answer (score 1):

For you two examples, you need to escape space and egual in file name (with \ character), and escape escape character too.
So `a a` have to be `a\ a` when passing to tail, and `a+b-c\ = e` have to be `a+b-c\\\ \=\ e`.
You can use sed to make this replacement.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608112/escape-filenames-using-the-same-way-bash-do-it) give you an better and easier way to make this replacement :

```
printf '%q' "$Strange_filename"
```

Comment: I followed your advice with `start_file1=$(echo $start_file | sed 's/ /\\ /g')`
 which yields `./a\ a` for `a a` but tail still complaints invalid option --1