# Printing boost path on windows with escaped backslashes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I need to print out a path (stored as boost filesystem path) to file, to be parsed back to path later.
The parser expects paths in windows platform to be escaped, so a path like

```
c:\path\to\file
```

will appear in the file as

```
c:\\path\\to\\file
```

Is there a method in boost path to do this? or do i need to process the output of string() method to add the escapes?

Comment: The _"escaping"_ of  `\ ` is only needed in character array or string literals. You must be confusing something.

Comment: @TheDude I think it's pretty clearly stated that whatever this other parser program is, it actually wants doubled backslashes in the text file, for whatever reason.

Comment: @aschepler In that case I don't see a problem with simply using [`std::string::replace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) before saving to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Did you hear about [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)?

It can be handy for things like this. Alternatively, use the power of your shell (e.g. [Escape FileNames Using The Same Way Bash Do It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608112/escape-filenames-using-the-same-way-bash-do-it/5608358#5608358))

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/524655dc1b6601fd)</kbd>**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::quoted(R"(c:\path\to\file)") << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::quoted("c:\\path\\to\\file") << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
"c:\\path\\to\\file"
"c:\\path\\to\\file"
```

> Note: also shows [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: @VladKeel it's not hard to make something similar: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14c764b4661e2318

Comment: Oh, that was obviously meant to be compiled [in c++03 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b618e02d2c6fa06)